# Using move_base for navigation, obstacle cannot be cleared timely

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am using move_base for navigation with a SICK laser scanner. I have set the local cost map update frequency to 30Hz.
However, the obstacle cannot be cleared timely when the obstacle such as a walking person moved away. The costmap will not be updated until the robot move.

For example, in the attached figure. The walking person in the green axis has moved away, but the costmap cannot clear the obstacle timely. Thus, the robot will be stuck in the virtual corner. The red axis is the robot heading direction.

[image: image description]

The parameter settings are:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.165
inflation_radius: 0.30
max_obstacle_height: 0.6
min_obstacle_height: 0.0
observation_sources: scan
scan: {sensor_frame: /laser, expected_update_rate: 30, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}   
 
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 0.0
  rolling_window: false
  static_map: true
  resolution: 0.05
  transform_tolerance: 2.0
  map_type: costmap


local_costmap:
  global_frame: /odom
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 30.0 
  publish_frequency: 10.0  
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
  transform_tolerance: 2.0
  map_type: costmap
obstacle_layer:
    observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
    laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true, observation_persistence: 0.0, expected_update_rate: 0.0, max_obstacle_height: 2.0, min_obstacle_height: -2.0, obstacle_range: 4.0, raytrace_range: 5.0, inf_is_valid: false}
    max_obstacle_height: 2.0
    obstacle_range: 4.0
    raytrace_range: 5.0
    track_unknown_space: false
```

move_base parameters:

```
controller_frequency: 3.0
recovery_behavior_enabled: false
clearing_rotation_allowed: false

TrajectoryPlannerROS:
   max_vel_x: 0.5
   min_vel_x: 0.03
   max_vel_y: 0.0   
   min_vel_y: 0.0
   min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.5
   max_vel_theta: 0.25
   min_vel_theta: -0.25
   escape_vel: -0.1
   acc_lim_x: 2.5
   acc_lim_y: 0.0 
   acc_lim_theta: 3.2

   holonomic_robot: false
   yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.15  
   xy_goal_tolerance: 0.15  
   latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false
   pdist_scale: 1.2
   gdist_scale: 0.6
   meter_scoring: true

   heading_lookahead: 0.5  
   heading_scoring: false
   heading_scoring_timestep: 0.8
   occdist_scale: 0.2 
   oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
   publish_cost_grid_pc: false
   prune_plan: true

   sim_time: 1.0
   sim_granularity: 0.025
   angular_sim_granularity: 0.025
   vx_samples: 8
   vy_samples: 0 
   vtheta_samples: 20
   dwa: true
   simple_attractor: false
```

Thank you very much,
Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221066/using-move_base-for-navigation,-obstacle-cannot-be-cleared-timely/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-11-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-17**:
Can you provide more information like your move_base parameters?

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2015-11-18**:
The parameters are posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

If you have time problems with the obstacle upate in your costmap, i think you should increase the publish frequency in your local_costmap params, since this is the frequency at the map the robot uses is updated. If this doesnt help maybe there is a problem with the sensor.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1